# "read localhost" appearing in status bar preventing page from fully loaded

Tags: browser

WIthout posting any code i was wondering if anyone might have an idea as to why "read localhost" would be appearing on the left hand side of the status bar (where "done" or "trasferring data from ..." usually is displayed.

Although the page is almost completely functional at this point it is preventing some javascript events from being binded.

Comment: Some more info is needed.  What brower are you using?  What is the URL you are entering? etc....

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem, using Firefox 3.5.5 viewing a website in the Visual studio 2008 debug server on a non-standard port number. The same page loads in IE7 (albeit slowly). My best guess at the moment is a Javascript issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning off Firebug?

In my case (detailed in the comment on the original question), I got this message in the Firefox status bar because it turns out I had set a breakpoint in Firebug's javascript debugger, but had minimised Firebug and forgotten about the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it seems a bug of the extension I used for Firefox. (Statusbar 4ever). 
I deactivated the extension and the firefox default statusbar works fine now. I lost some features of the extension, but the "read localhost" is gone.